# Hobby or not? How do I know if I can ask?

Tags: support, questions

I have a question about a ways to covering OSB edges. I'm not a professional, but I build (and helped to build) furniture since childhood. So I know my basics pretty solid, I think. So can I legally ask this, or not? And is there a canonical meta question about it?

The question I was going to ask is:

> I have an [oriented standard board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_strand_board), 1250 x 1800 x 12 mm. Faces are covered with fabric. Sadly, fabric's width was exactly 1250mm, too. This means I was able to tuck fabric to cover shorter edges, but now I have uncovered 1800 x 12 mm OSB edges. How can I make them safe to handle, and look good? I don't want any splinters in my skin. Look is important, but clearly secondary issue. Due to technical requirements OSB can't really be narrower, and the kind of fabric I use is not sold in wider varieties.

Comment: For those of us not familiar with the terminology what's "OSB"?

Comment: @ChrisF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_strand_board - When I searched this site to see if question similar to mine was already asked, I've seen this acronym used without explanation, so I believed it is widely used term, like plywood for example. But maybe it's know under other name? Or less known than I believed?

Comment: There are a number of terms that people assume everybody knows. If I see things like that I'd seriously consider editing the first use to define it. It all helps especially as there are some terms that are different on opposite sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for reminder :) If I'll ever ask this question on the main site, I'll keep it in mind. Sadly, I still don't know if it's on-topic or not.

Comment: This looks off topic to me, either hobby or "decorating advice" since the suggestion could easily be made add a second layer of fabric which may not look good, at which point you get into subjective answers.

Answer (score 2):

We tend to reject questions about furniture. However, we often accept questions about *built-in* furniture.

Your question would probably be okay if you couched it in terms like,

> *I am installing a shelf and have a flexible covering (cloth) that is exactly the width of the shelf with no excess to cover the exposed front edge. How can I cover this edge to make it safe and aesthetically appealing (yes, I know aesthetics are fairly subjective).*

You might get answers about edging techniques or shifting the covering material and using molding in the back or other techniques that cross over between furniture and trim carpentry.